# Windows Forms - display changing values

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a `Form` I'm trying to display changing value in a `TextBox`:

```
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Start(i);
    } 
}
public void Start(int i)
{
    textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
    Thread.Sleep(200);
}
```

Only last value of the loop is displayed. Why?

Comment: Because the GUI never has a chance to refresh.  Use a timer or a background thread.

Comment: @LarsTech thank you, I have used textBox1.Update() and it is working, but I'm not sure it is a right solution.

Comment: No, it's not.  Refer to my second sentence.  StackOverflow has covered this topic extensively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a thread called a UI thread, which is responsible for updating the GUI.  When the button is clicked this event runs on the UI thread.  So your `Start` function is also running on the UI thread.  The UI thread is busy running the `Start` function so it doesn't have a chance to update the textbox until the `Start` function completes.  Once the `Start` function completes the UI thread updates the textbox to the last value.

What you need to do is run your `Start` function on another thread, so the UI thread is free to update the textbox.  There are a few ways you could do this.  Here's one example:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer;
private int _timer_i;

public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  _timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer()
  {
    Enabled = false,
    Interval = 200
  };
  _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
}

private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  textBox1.Text = _timer_i.ToString();
  _timer_i++;
  if (_timer_i >= 10)
  {
    _timer.Stop();
  }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  _timer.Stop();
  _timer_i = 0;
  _timer.Start();
}
```